# String to tuple of words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I define a word as a sequence of characters (from a to Z) which might also contain an apostrophe. I wish to split a sentence into words, with the apostrophes removed from the words.

I'm currently doing the following to get the words from a piece of text.

```
import re
text = "Don't ' thread \r\n on \nme ''\n "
words_iter = re.finditer(r'(\w|\')+', text)
words = (word.group(0).lower() for word in words_iter)
for i in words:
    print(i)
```

This gives me:

```
don't
'
thread
on
me
''
```

But what I wan't is:

```
dont
thread
on
me
```

How can I change my code to achieve this?

**Please note that there is no `'` in my output.**

**I also wish for `words` to be a generator.**

Comment: Aren't you almost there, just add an `i = i.replace("'", "")` in your `for` loop and then yield the string if it's non-empty?

Comment: How much input are you trying to parse?

Comment: @Tritium21 I'm building a corpus, so I'm processing text files of different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for Regex.

```
import re

text = "Don't ' thread \r\n on \nme ''\n "

# Define a function so as to make a generator
def get_words(text):

    # Find each block, separated by spaces
    for section in re.finditer("[^\s]+", text):

        # Get the text from the selection, lowercase it
        # (`.lower()` for Python 2 or if you hate people who use Unicode)
        section = section.group().casefold()

        # Filter so only letters are kept and yield
        section = "".join(char for char in section if char.isalpha())
        if section:
            yield section

list(get_words(text))
#>>> ['dont', 'thread', 'on', 'me']
```

Explanation of Regex:

```
[^    # An "inverse set" of characters, matches anything that isn't in the set
\s    # Any whitespace character
]+    # One or more times
```

So this matches any block of non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Note that this is around 4 times slower than my version.

Comment: I'll accept that timing after you add `.casefold`/`.lower` to yours. ;) Mine's more technically correct 'cause I check whether `isalpha` rather than remove ASCII punctuation, too, but I'll let that slide.

Comment: I think you can lower it once, using `.lower()` in the `re.finditer` call.

Comment: That'll work on the whole string at once, though, which we want to avoid.

Comment: Updated my solution with new timings.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = (x.replace("'", '') for x in text.split())
result = tuple(x for x in words if x)
```

...does just one iteration over the split data.

If the data set is large, use `re.finditer` instead of `str.split()` to avoid reading the entire data set into memory:

```
words = (x.replace("'", '') for x in re.finditer(r'[^\s]+', text))
result = tuple(x for x in words if x)
```

...although, `tuple()`-ing the data will read everything in memory anyway.

Comment: wont strip the ' in "don't"

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.translate` and `re.finditer`:

```
>>> text = "Don't ' thread \r\n on \nme ''\n "
>>> import re
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> tab = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, punctuation))
def solve(text):
    for m in re.finditer(r'\b(\S+)\b', text):
        x = m.group(1).translate(tab).lower()
        if x : yield x
>>> list(solve(text))
['dont', 'thread', 'on', 'me']
```

### Timing comparison:

```
>>> strs = text * 1000
>>> %timeit list(solve(strs))
10 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(get_words(strs))
10 loops, best of 3: 36.7 ms per loop
>>> strs = text * 10000
>>> %timeit list(solve(strs))
1 loops, best of 3: 146 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(get_words(strs))
1 loops, best of 3: 411 ms per loop
```

Comment: `text.split()` processes the whole shebang at once, Baz wants to process cumulatively.

Comment: Nice, but what about dashes? "word1---word2 word3"

Comment: @hcwhsa text.lower() will create a copy of text which I wish to avoid since it can be very big

Comment: @hcwhsa As I stated in my question, I only define a word to include from a to Z plus apostrophes. Your code will pass through letters from non English alphabets and numbers etc.

Comment: @Baz You can use regex for that: `x = re.sub(r'[^a-z]+', '', m.group(1), flags=re.I).lower()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
tuple(str(filter(lambda x: x if x in string.letters + string.whitespace else '', "strings don't have '")).split())
```

Comment: As with hcwhsa's, `text.split()` processes the whole shebang at once, Baz wants to process cumulatively.